# EF 4.1 CodeFirst and Enumerations

Tags: c#, .net, enums, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I have a class like that:

```
public class Customer
{
  public string Name {get; set; }
  public enumGender Gender {get; set; }
}

public enum enumGender 
{
    Male,
    Female
}
```

I`m trying to use this as entity and i want to map gender to the database as int, right now gender of course doesn't get mapped at all.

any idea how to do that

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is how i got over it....

```
public class Customer
{
  public string Name {get; set; }
        public int gender { get; set; }
        public enumGender Gender
        {
            get { return (CodeFirstEF.Gender) gender; }
            set { gender = (int) value; }
        }
}

public enum enumGender 
{
    Male,
    Female
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option, would be upgrading to the June CTP of Entity Framework, which now supports enums.  http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=26660

This has been working wonderfully for me.